# Is the tier-based Cultivation system due to modern, possibly LitRPG, influence, or does it come from earlier sources?

Tags: history-of, cultivation, litrpg

How much of the [tier-based Cultivation](https://immortalmountain.wordpress.com/glossary/wuxia-xianxia-xuanhuan-terms/#cultivation) system is a modern creation?

As that link says:

> Ranks / Levels / Layers (级 jí) (层 céng) – a common way to quantify martial power or the progress made in cultivation. In many cases (although not all) where these are used, there are 9 ranks/levels/layers to each stage of cultivation, with rank 1 being the start and rank 9 being the peak. After breaking through to the next stage, the practitioner starts at rank 1 of that new stage.

And for history of Cultivation / Xianxia Novels, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xianxia_(genre)#History):

> Xianxia novels were popularized during the [[Republic of China (1912–1949)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_China_(1912%E2%80%931949))] period, but it was the 1932 novel [Legend of the Swordsmen of the Mountains of Shu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_the_Swordsmen_of_the_Mountains_of_Shu) that sparked the modern popularity of the genre.[citation needed]

I know that such a deep ranking system was used in modern stories, but English Wikipedia's info on *Legend of the Swordsmen of the Mountains of Shu*, a.k.a 蜀山剑侠传, is very sparse.

[Google Translated Chinese Wikipedia's page](https://zh-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/%E8%9C%80%E5%B1%B1%E5%89%91%E4%BE%A0%E4%BC%A0?_x_tr_sl=zh-CN&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp) has a list of characters and magical artifacts and such, but nothing about Cultivation rankings.

I want to know if there's any cultivation story from the previous century with ranking systems like modern ones, instead of just the romantic dual-cultivation that's mentioned at the end of the translated 蜀山剑侠传 page's third section.

Comment: I haven't done a ton of research yet, but is your criteria being that numbers are attached to the levels? Or just that they're sequential and must be followed in order?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - More that they're sequential, because numbers can be replaced by words pretty easily, like how 1, 2, 3 could be Novice, Apprentice, Journeyman, in other systems.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - And on thinking about ranking systems, my theory of "Ranking is too modern" basically collapses. Gonna figure out how to rewrite this question a bit. Focus on origin, perhaps.

Comment: This seems very opinion-based. Um, lots? Some? Not much? I fail to see what a good answer would look like

Comment: @Valorum - Added easier criteria: Basically, "are there Xianxia from the previous century, and if so, do they use a ranking system?"

Comment: @Malady - I would edit this question with an axe to just focus on that issue.

Comment: @Valorum - swapped out some info, at least now I know that Cultivation likely happens in "Legend of the Swordsmen of the Mountains of Shu".

Comment: @Malady - Since this question has attracted a number of close votes, you might want to edit it to indicate that you're looking for the _earliest known instance_ of such a story. That should still address the point you seem to be curious about, while making it easier for other users to interpret what a good answer would look like.

Comment: @LogicDictates - Thanks! ... Not sure if saying "Are there any such stories written before 1950, ELSE IF what's the oldest" is too many questions for one question, though.

Comment: @Malady - If I were you, I'd keep it simple and only ask for the earliest known instance. Other users will then then be incentivised to look for the earliest instances they can find, which should clarify whether there are any known instances from before 1950. Keep in mind that three or more close votes have already been cast on this question, so there's a strong possibility that it'll be closed in its current form.

Comment: @LogicDictates - That makes sense, the age of the oldest *is* an indirect answer to my question.